# toggle textbox if checkbox is true for CMS

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make something like that work, implementing it in my CMS:

Fixed CMS part:

```
<div class="RadioList" id="radioListId">
    <div class="TxtLbl" id="textLblId"> Question </div>
    <span id="spanId">
        <input value="yes"></input>
        <input value="no"></input>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="TxtBox" id="txtBoxId">
some text
</div>
```

own JS part someting like:

```
function EnableTextbox(radioListId,spanId)
{
    if(document.getElementById(radioListId).inputValue == "yes")
        document.getElementById(textBoxId).visibility = visible;
    else
        document.getElementById(textBoxId).visibility = hidden;
}
```

But I am not quite sure how to put it correctly - my understanding of js is not really high enough.
Any helping comments are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="RadioList" id="radioListId">
    <div class="TxtLbl" id="textLblId">Question</div> <span id="spanId">
        <input type="radio" value="yes" name="showhide"> Show</input>
        <input type="radio" value="no" name="showhide"> Hide</input>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="TxtBox" id="txtBoxId">some text</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtBoxId").hide();
    $("input[name='showhide']").on("click", function () {
        var option = $(this).attr('value');
        if (option == "yes") {
            $("#txtBoxId").show();
        } else {
            $("#txtBoxId").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hLbnfx2n/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few changes you need to make:

- the inputs need to have a `type="radio"` to indicate that those are radio buttons.
- the inputs need to have a common `name="whatever"` to indicate that both belong to same group and cannot be checked simultaneously.
- the inputs need to have a text between the opening/closing tags, this text appears next to the radio button.
- you need to call the javascript function when you click/change the buttons, and inside you check which radio was selected.
- you pass the radio button reference into the javascript function by writing `this` as the function variable.
- inside the function you retrieve the radio button reference, you can name the variable whatever you want.
- you are using `visible` and `hidden` as variables, but those are not defined. it supposed to be either a string, or a boolean value. i prefer to use css for that purpose.

here is an <kbd>**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/6npu906u/)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="RadioList" id="radioListId">
    <div class="TxtLbl" id="textLblId">Question</div> <span id="spanId">
        <input type="radio" value="yes" onclick="EnableTextbox(this);" name="Answer">Yes</input>
        <input type="radio" value="no"  onclick="EnableTextbox(this);" name="Answer">No</input>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="TxtBox" id="txtBoxId">some text</div>
```

JS:

```
function EnableTextbox(radioList) {
    if (radioList.value == "yes") document.getElementById("txtBoxId").style.visibility = "visible";
    else document.getElementById("txtBoxId").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery

```
   <span id="spanId">
      <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="yes" />
      <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="no" />
   </span>



$('#spanId input:radio[name="radiobutton"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'yes'){
       $('#txtBoxId').show();
    } else {
       $('#txtBoxId').hide();
    }
});
```

Explanation

```
$('#txtBoxId').show() = display:block;
$('#txtBoxId').hide() = display:none;
```

If you want visibility instead.

```
$('#txtBoxId').css('visibility','visible');
$('#txtBoxId').css('visibility','hidden');
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: 1) he needs radio buttons not checkboxes, 2) your code doesnt explain how to trigger the check 3) he didnt ask about jquery.

Comment: 1) The title of this question is "toggle textbox if checkbox is true for CMS". 2) He wants to hide/show div not trigger. 3) Alright he is using javascript, I just want to help.

Comment: he made a mistake in the title. a yes/no option can never be checkboxes, and yes, he needs help with calling the function on input change not on page load otherwise he wouldnt have used inputs.. and its alright mate no offence, i just downvoted your answer because it doesnt answer the question at all...

Comment: No worries, I just want to help. Just updated a jQuery solution but thats fine. :)

Comment: i removed my downvote, you still have a spelling mistake , should be 'txtBoxId'

Comment: Cool. Updated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since onclick="" is outdated you should use the `element.addEventListener();`!

Here is an Example in **[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/a8v5gyzx/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="RadioList" id="radioListId">
    <div class="TxtLbl" id="textLblId"> Question </div>
    <span id="spanId">
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="yes" value="yes" />Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="no" value="no"/>No</label>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="TxtBox" id="txtBoxId">
some text
</div>
```

JS:

```
var yes = document.getElementById('yes');
var no_ = document.getElementById('no');
if (yes.addEventListener) {
    yes.addEventListener ("RadioStateChange", OnChange, false);
    no_.addEventListener ("RadioStateChange", OnChange, false);
}
function OnChange(){
      if (yes.checked) {
          document.getElementById('txtBoxId').style.display = 'inline';
      }
      else {
          document.getElementById('txtBoxId').style.display = 'none';
      }
}
```

Greetings from Vienna

Comment: Hi Bernd, I am sorry the solution didnt work for me, thanks for your work and the info that onclick is outdated. Where do you get your info to be state of the art all the time if I may ask?